# Masm Bitwise Operations on Constants

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, masm

Does Masm support bitwise operations on constants? For example in Nasm you can write something like this:

```
%define foo 00010000b
%define bar 00000011b
```

...

```
mov r8b, foo | bar
```

In Masm I tried:

```
foo equ 00010000b
bar equ 00000011b
```

...

```
mov r8b, foo | bar
```

Which causes: "Error A2044  invalid character in file"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of MASM's logical operators are:

- [OR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k27ee19w.aspx)
- [AND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk35xcha.aspx)
- [NOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/783262e1.aspx)
- [XOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6aa8syk.aspx)
- [SHL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1a6wss8.aspx)
- [SHR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e32h9w5d.aspx)

For a complete reference, see the official documentation of the [MASM operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94b6khh4.aspx).